# url rewriting using .htaccess - role of ? in target

Tags: .htaccess, url, rewriting

Hi Can someone explain what this rule will exactly do. I want to know what is the role of ? towards the end.

```
RewriteRule ^(products/someproduct.html)$ https://www.myserver.com/? [R=301,L]
```

looking forward for a quick explanation on the last character **?**

Comment: If a particular answer is helpful in solving your problem, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the little checkmark next to it. If your questions are receiving unhelpful answers, clarify what you're looking for or leave constructive comments on the answers explaining how they fall short.

Answer (score 2):

This prevent appending the query string to the new URL.

for example, a request for  `https://www.myserver.com/products/someproduct.html?qu=1&bu=2`:

**with `?`** : get redirected to `https://www.myserver.com/`
**without `?`** : get redirected to `https://www.myserver.com/?qu=1&bu=2`